# Несколько колонок средствами CSS

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Для формирования колонок в основном используются DIV.
Какие могут быть сложности, если колонки сделать используя `<ul><li></li></ul>` ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложностей никаких, за исключением того, что динамические колонки(текстовые) на чистом HTML сделать невозможно в принципе.

Если под колонками подразумевается способ верстки сайта, настоятельно рекомендуется использовать DIV, чтобы избежать лишней возни. Чтобы вообще избежать возни (при отсутствие опыта разработки) вообще рекомендуются таблицы: меньше шансов налажать с версткой. Но гибкость(и простота дальнейшей модификации) теряется многократно, поэтому их никто не любит.

Comment: Чушь! Текстовые колонки делаются на чистом css через незамудренные хаки. Вот [пример](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/vgOaQm) сетки, но с картинками и галереей. Там может быть и текст внутри, легко. На css-tricks точно такой же способ использован для представления любой информации в виде карточек.

Answer (score 0):

Как выше было отмечено, для верстки лучше использовать `<div>`. Где можно верстать колонки списком? Например, в горизонтальном меню, где каждый пункт по-сути является колонкой. Сложностей на использование никаких: располагаем элементы списка в ряд, а для самого списка сбрасываем отображение маркеров.

Вообще-то говоря, если идет некое перечисление блоков, т.е. все они имеют некую общую точку, как, например, пункты меню привязаны к меню, то почему-бы и не сверстать списком. Вот, кстати, пример, где блоки Consultancy, Development и Workshops сверстаны списком http://csswizardry.com/