# Разделение списка на несколько колонок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется список, пункты которого должны следовать друг за другом по вертикали, а по достижении нижней границы родителя с фиксированной высотой - переноситься в новую колонку.

Реализация с помощью `column-count` располагает пункты списка друг за другом по вертикали, но список разделен на три столбца с одинаковым количеством пунктов, а нужно чтобы первые столбцы были заполнены по высоте на все 100%.

```css
.category-list {
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 3;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.category-list li {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list clearfix">
  <li class="category-item">1</li>
  <li class="category-item">2</li>
  <li class="category-item">3</li>
  <li class="category-item">4</li>
  <li class="category-item">5</li>
  <li class="category-item">6</li>
  <li class="category-item">7</li>
  <li class="category-item">8</li>
  <li class="category-item">9</li>
  <li class="category-item">10</li>
  <li class="category-item">11</li>
  <li class="category-item">12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `display: flex;`

Вот полная документация: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.category-list {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.category-list li {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list clearfix">
  <li class="category-item">1</li>
  <li class="category-item">2</li>
  <li class="category-item">3</li>
  <li class="category-item">4</li>
  <li class="category-item">5</li>
  <li class="category-item">6</li>
  <li class="category-item">7</li>
  <li class="category-item">8</li>
  <li class="category-item">9</li>
  <li class="category-item">10</li>
  <li class="category-item">11</li>
  <li class="category-item">12</li>
</ul>
```