# Как расположить блоки (по вертикали) по три в ряд?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

Что-то не придумать мне как располагать блоки по три в вертикальный ряд, может вы подскажите?

Есть форма с горизонтальным скроллом.

Надо что бы она наполнялась по принципу: сначала вниз до трёх, потом в следующий ряд (правее).

Наглядно это выглядит примерно так:

```
[1]
[2]
```

Потом

```
[1][4]
[2][5]
[3]
```

Ну и так далее:

```
[1][4][7]
[2][5]
[3][6]
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/vgOaQm

Comment: Дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок/619962#619962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант flexbox

```css
.container {
   height:200px;
  width:500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
 }
  
.item {
   margin:20px 2px;
  background:red;
  widtth:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
   <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
```

Вариант c columns

```css
.container {
    columns: 130px 6;
    column-gap: 40px;
  width:400px
  }
.item {
      padding: 10px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
   <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё решилось с помощью flex`a :)

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 400px;
}
.wrapper .item {
 width: 25%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: gray;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```