# Как сделать список блоков разной высоты в несколько колонок?

Tags: html, css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте. Появился вот такой нюанс. Мне нужно сверстать секцию, в которой блоки расположены как-бы кирпичиками, из-за того, что высота изображения в каждом будет разная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я для всех блоков открыл одну строку **row**, потом каждый блок поместил в **col-lg-4**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но тогда получается вот так, как на картинке ниже, из-за того, что **row** имеет `display: flex;` и каждый **col-lg-4** получается одинаковой высоты. А мне нужно как-то сделать чтобы колонки, которые снизу подсосались к верху, чтобы не было пустого пространства, и было все кирпичиками. Падскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно такое можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие стили применяли? Пробовали через 'display: inline-block' сделать?

Comment: display: inline-block только что попробовал, тоже самое, колонки col ведь будут все равно одинаковой высоты. Можно было бы в одну колонку поместить по два блока, но тогда при интеграции WordPress будут небольшие сложности, так то ты просто берешь и выводишь через цыкл одинаковый код каждого блока из шаблона

Comment: masonry подключите и не мучайтесь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для данной задачи есть несколько решений.

### Каждый столбец отдельным блоком

```css
.el {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">  
    <div class="el" style="height:30px"> </div>
    <div class="el" style="height:60px"> </div>
    <div class="el" style="height:110px"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">  
    <div class="el" style="height:80px"> </div>
    <div class="el" style="height:30px"> </div>
    <div class="el" style="height:40px"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Количество элементов в каждом столбце надо будет рассчитать вручную.

### Списком, и указать `column-count`

```css
ul {
  column-count:2;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="height:30px"> </li>
  <li style="height:60px"> </li>
  <li style="height:20px"> </li>
  <li style="height:70px"> </li>
  <li style="height:120px"> </li>
  <li style="height:30px"> </li>
  <li style="height:50px"> </li>
  <li style="height:140px"> </li>
</ul>
```

В этом случае количество элементов в колонке указывать не надо, оно будет расчитано автоматически, зато адаптивность придётся прописывать вручную, через media query менять количество столбцов.

### Flexbox

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 400px;
}

.el {
   background-color: gray;
   margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el" style="height:30px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:40px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:50px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:60px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:110px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:80px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:90px"> </div>
  <div class="el" style="height:120px"> </div>
</div>
```

В данном решении высоту flex контейнера надо будет рассчитать вручную.

Comment: (+) хороший ответ, поздравляю со второй тысячей

Comment: @Alexandr_T Постарался сделать красивый и полный ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, большое , Дмитрий, ваш ответ мне очень помог

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий)